# Syntax of inline flags in re module

Tags: python, regex

What would be the correct syntax to use with the inline `(?aiLmsux)`
 flags in the [`re module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re)? For example:

```
string = 'Hello There'
re.search(r'^(?i[a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?', string)
```

The above is an invalid python expression, but basically I would like the first `[a-z]+` to do a case-insensitive match, so the matched string will be "Hello".

The closest I have been able to get is:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?i)([a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?', string).group()
'Hello There'

# also, not what I want
>>> re.search(r'^([a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?', string, re.I).group()
'Hello There'
```

But this flag is working on the entire string, and not just the first `[a-z]+` part. How could I limit the scope of the `?i` ?

**Update**: Note, the linked duplicate shows how to use the `re.I` flag as well as the `(?i)` flag on an entire string, but I'm looking how (if?) it's possible to only apply that flag on a grouped sub-expresssion.

The equivalent regex should be:

```
# Only the first part -- [a-zA-Z] is made case-insensitive
>>> re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-z]+)?', string).group()
'Hello'
```

Comment: @b_c the answer there is using a flag, also I'd only like it to work on part of a string.

Comment: Gotcha, missed the "partial" part :)

Comment: The marked duplicate here is not a complete answer as of 11/2019. Does not tell the complete inline modifier usage in Python. I recommend @WiktorStribiżew  not point (as _duplicates_) all the Python inline modifier questions  to that single answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will (should) isolate the flag to the local group `(?flag: )`

`^(?i:[a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?`

Seems to work in Python 3.7.3

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^(?i:[a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?','Hello There').group()
'Hello'
>>>
```

But has a problem on regex101.com version of Python (whatever that is)

https://regex101.com/r/JZ79ul/1

Note also this scenario, which can overcome Python's shortcomings via
modifiers.

```
 >>> import re
 >>> re.search(r"(?-i:ab(?i:cd)ef(?i:gh))", "abCDeFgh abCDefGH")
 <re.Match object; span=(9, 17), match='abCDefGH'>
```

There is more to the story of course which aren't addressed anywhere on SO
apparently.
It seems a waste of time to tell it here, in a post that is buried now.

Comment: yes, this is the correct answer! `>>> import re;re.match(r'^(?i:[a-z]+)(\s[a-z]+)?','Hello There').group() 'Hello'`